# VideoView error only on real device

Tags: android, android-videoview

In fragment i have videoview and play a recorded whit emulator camera .mp4 video. Everything is fine and in the emulator the video is playing, but on real device when i try to play another video, recorded again whit my camera in .mp4 format the screen go black and eclipse sad "BitmapFactory class. source not found". I'm testing on 4.0.4 devices and target is from 8 to 17 api. Images is opening fine to on emulator and on real device. No LOGcat error, all is green...

Fragment code

```
public class PreviewFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
//variable
File file;
boolean image;
//views
VideoView videView;
ImageView imageView;
ImageButton imageButton;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preview, container, false);
    //elements
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    videView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    //variables from activity
    file = ((PreviewActivity)getActivity()).file;
    image = ((PreviewActivity)getActivity()).image;


    //main run
    if(image == true) {
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
    else {
        videView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        videView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
        videView.requestFocus();
        videView.start();
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

and xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/text_fullscreen" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but, in emulator on 4.1 if i play video in fragment its playing, but on real 4.0 devices the video must be host in activity to play, in this way the video is playing in emulator and in real device. Don`t know why but it work this way.